# Laravel: How to remove item from multidimensional collection by value

Tags: php, laravel

So my output is something like this, but can vary:

```
{
    "4": {
        "position": "0",
        "type_id": "1",
        "miles": "0",
        "drop_hooks": "0",
        "different": "off"
    },
    "8": {
        "position": "1",
        "type_id": "3",
        "miles": "0",
        "drop_hooks": "0",
        "tray_count": "0",
        "roll_offs": "0",
        "pack_outs": "0",
        "different": "off"
    }
}
```

How can I remove (unset) any item (`miles`, `drop_hooks`, `tray_count`, etc) that is equal to zero?

**Note:** Sometimes `position` can be zero. I do not want to remove/unset `position` from the collection.

**Edit:** Desired Result:

```
{
    "4": {
        "position": "0",
        "type_id": "1",
        "different": "off"
    },
    "8": {
        "position": "1",
        "type_id": "3",
        "different": "off"
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add the result wanted to your question to make it clearer, but for as far as i know, you need to loop twice to check for attributes emptiness. either after conversion into array (easier) or before

Comment: Updated the answer to the new condition

Comment: @N69S new condition? do you mean desired result? if so, done.

Comment: have none of the answer below worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a double loop solution starting from collection

```php
$groups = $collection->toArray();
foreach($groups as $groupIndex => $group) {
    foreach($group as $attName => $attValue) {
        if ($attValue === "0" && $attName != "position") {
            unset($groups[$groupIndex][$attName]);
        }
    }
}
return json_encode($groups);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out unwanted content:

```php
function filterEmpty(&$array) {
    $array = array_filter(
        $array,
        function ($key, $value) {
             return $key == 'position' || !is_numeric($value) || (int) $value > 0
        },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
    );
}


array_walk($fooArray, 'filterEmpty');
```

Comment: Did you mean `!is_numeric($value)` ?